# how to preg_replace Ckeditor added multiple <br /> s

Tags: php, regex, ckeditor, preg-replace

I am using CKeditor with KCfinder. When adding  blog posts; when I want to add a photo I create a 2 rows table. At the top part , I upload a photo and at the bottom part I write a caption.

The problem is that when I publish the post , I realize many line breaks are added to my post. When I check page source :

```
<br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:650px"><br />
    <tbody><br />
        <tr><br />
            <td><img alt="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Adalar_6954.jpg/800px-Adalar_6954.jpg" style="height:518px; width:700px" /></td><br />
        </tr><br />
        <tr><br />
            <td style="text-align:center"><em><span style="font-size:10px">Heybeliada Ruhban Okulu, Fotoğraf: <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Adalar_6954.jpg">Wikimedia Commons</a></span></em></td><br />
        </tr><br />
    </tbody><br />
</table><br />
```

.

I am trying to clean those using regex but still I cant manage

```
{{  preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>\s*?){2,}#', '<br />',$post->content())  }}
```

Can someone guide me to use it correctly ?

Thank You

Comment: make sure you are using the latest version of CKeditor, it does a better job with the html

Comment: I downloaded yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all unwanted breaks use regex pattern

```
#(?:(?<=<t[rd]>)|(?<=</t[rd]>)|(?<=<t(?:body|able)>)|(?<=</t(?:body|able)>))<br\s*/>#
```

Comment: this removes unwanted <br /> in the table ..when I save a post ? editor gives an empty line between <p>...</p> tags. this gives a huge space between paragraphs  do you have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: @ytsejam - The issue you described in your comment is a new task, so please open/submit a new question for that problem and be sure to list an example of the code that has unwanted space characters inside...

Comment: thank you very much. your answer did the job for my question.